# How to compare more than two numbers in parallel?

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, sse, sse4

Is it possible to compare more than a pair of numbers in one instruction using SSE4?

[Intel Reference](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/2/d/5/17971-intel_20sse4_20programming_20reference.pdf) says the following about PCMPGTQ

> PCMPGTQ — Compare Packed Data for Greater Than
>
> Performs an SIMD compare for the packed quadwords in the destination
>   operand  (first operand) and the source operand (second operand). If
>   the data element in the  first (destination) operand is greater than
>   the corresponding element in the second  (source) operand, the
>   corresponding data element in the destination is set to all 1s; 
>   otherwise, it is set to 0s.

which is not really what I want because I want to be able to decide which integers are greater and which are smaller in the vector.

For example, if I need to compare

```
32 with 45
13 with 78
44 with 12
99 with 66
```

I was planning to put `[32, 13, 44, 99]` in one vector and `[45, 78, 12, 66]` in another vector and compare them using SSE4 in one instruction, and have `[0, 0, 1, 1]` as result (0 - less, 1 - greater)

But it seems this is not what PCMPGTQ does. Any suggestions on how to use parallelism at this level to speedup this comparison?

Comment: You can just AND the result of `PCMPGTQ` by `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually I misinterpreted, PCMPGTQ actually does what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is actually what the `PCMPGT` family of operators does. The suffix specifies the size of the elements - `B` for 8-bit elements, `W` for 16-bit elements, `D` for 32-bit elements, `Q` for 64-bit elements. So, if you want to compare 4 32-bit numbers at once, use `PCMPGTD` with 128-bit vector arguments. See [this page](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc232.htm) for a pseudocode description of these opcodes.

They don't write just `1` or `0`, though; they write all-ones or all-zeroes to each element, so that comparing `0x1234567887654321` against `0x8765432112345678` using `PCMPGTB` should give `0x0000FFFFFFFF0000`.

[This Intel white paper](http://www.intel.in/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-64-assembly-lang-paper.pdf) gives a neat example of performing the operation `a[i] = (a[i] > b[i]) ? a[i] : b[i]` (i.e. `a[i] = max(a[i], b[i])`) using vector operations.

Comment: Thanks, makes some sense. But looks like this speedup doesnt give me much. I was able to compare 4 at a time, but how do I use the results? I will probably need to do something like `if ((int)result[0] == 0)` and thus will incur another comparison. I am definitely missing something.

Comment: @Lazer It depends on the surrounding code. If you're packing data just for a single comparison, then there's no way you'll get any speedup. You need to do a LOT of work while the data is packed before you will get any worthwhile speedup.

Comment: Well, of course it depends on what you want to do with it! There's a lot of neat tricks you can do with `xor` and `and` against this sort of all-ones vector.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo and @Mystical, I think I understand. I just need to figure a way to use these results in an optimal way.

Comment: @Lazer There's a reason why they have it return all 1s. Then you can use it as a mask to do cool stuff like vector conditional moves and such.

Comment: Yeah, see the link I (just) posted. They do basically `C=A; C=A>C; A^=B; C&=A; C^=B` to do `C = max(A,B)` with vectors.

Comment: Both links are now broken. Nobody cares about link stability anymore? Intel, come on!  [New URL for intel while paper (PDF)](http://www.intel.in/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-64-assembly-lang-paper.pdf)

Comment: @bluss: thanks! I've corrected the link in my answer.